# Determine the number of natural numbers smaller than $10^4$, in the decimal notation of which all the digits are distinct.

Tags: combinatorics

Determine the number of natural numbers smaller than $10^4$, in the decimal notation of which all the digits are distinct.

Please explain me the meaning of this question.

**I am not asking a homework question. I just didn't understood  meaning of this question. Please don't close my question**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that that you must find all numbers in the range $1 \le n < 10^4$ without duplicate digits in their decimal notation. In some schools the range of "natural number" is $0 \le n < 10^4$.

> $1234$

is allowed but not

> $1134$

because it contains a repetition.

Comment: sir, what does this** in the decimal notation of which all the digits are distinct** mean

Comment: I am sorry, I can't see the way the question is visible to you. I am explaning what you asked - what does "distinct digits" mean.

Comment: @jamesamajoe The decimal digits are $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9$.

Comment: sir,I am not getting what is use of decimal notation

Comment: Well, the binary notation $101010$ is the same number as the decimal notation $42$ and the same number as the octal notation $52$. In the binary notation the digits are not distinct, but in the decimal and octal notations, the digits are distinct.

Comment: Thanks to all great people here for helping me!!! I got correct answer.

Comment: @WeatherVane  I did

Comment: @GoodDeeds thanks for the MathJax edit.

Answer (score 2):

So first consider what we mean by a natural number in the decimal notation which is $\lt 10^4$. This is a positive integer with at most four digits.

We can write it as $$n=a_310^3+a_210^2+a_110^1+a_010^0=1000a_3+100a_2+10a_1+a_0$$
where we have $0\le a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3 \le 9$ and we normally write a decimal integer as a lot of digits with place value assumed $$n=a_3a_2a_1a_0$$ (where this is not multiplication but 'concatenation')

No repeated digits looks as though it means that $a_3, a_2, a_1, a_0$ are distinct when $n$ is expressed in this way. But some care is required with the digit zero, since we write $20$, which has no repeated digits, rather than $0020$, where the digits are repeated.

Comment: Thanks sir, for giving your precious time